# Connecting Ubuntu box into Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: software-recommendation, active-directory, likewise

I need to join my Ubuntu 12.04 PC to an Active Directory domain. I know that there are two applications that would help me do the job: LikewiseOpen and Centrify-DirectControl. But, before I choose which one to use, I will really appreciate your expert opinions and experience with these applications. Would like to get your feedback on ease of installation, stability, user friendliness, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to try Likewise

> Likewise Open graphical desktop utility for joining hosts to Active
>   Directory domains.

To install Likewise

click on this image [image: Install via the software center]

or from command line

```
sudo apt-get install likewise-open
```